# I can't register a user by fabric-ca

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I use the IBM example enrollUser.js to create a new user, before this work, I have successfully created admin.

```
Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({path: store_path
}).then((state_store) =>{
    // assign the store to the fabric client
    fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
    var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
    // use the same location for the state store (where the users' certification are kept)
    // and the crypto store (where the users' keys are kept)
    var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path});
    crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
    fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);
    var tlsOptions = {
        trustedRoots: [],
        verify: false
    };
    // be sure to change http to https when CA is running TLS enabled
    fabric_ca_client = new Fabric_CA_Client('http://localhost:7054', tlsOptions, 'ca.example.com', crypto_suite);

    // first check to see if the admin is already enrolled
    return fabric_client.getUserContext('admin', true);
}).then((user_from_store) => {
    if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
        console.log('Successfully loaded admin from persistence');
        admin_user = user_from_store;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Failed to get admin... run enrollAdmin.js');
    }

    // at this point we should have the admin user
    // first need to register the user with the CA server
    return fabric_ca_client.register({enrollmentID: 'user1', affiliation: 'org1.department1', role: 'client'}, admin_user);
}).then((secret) => {
    // next we need to enroll the user with CA server
    console.log('Successfully registered user1 - secret' + secret);
    return fabric_ca_client.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'user1', enrollmentSecret: secret } );
}).then((enrollment) => {
    console.log('Successfully enrolled member user "user1"');
    return fabric_client.createUser({
        username: 'user1',
        mspid: 'Org1MSP',
        cryptoContent: {privateKeyPEM: enrollment.key.toBytes(), signedCertPEM: enrollment.certificate}
    });
}).then((user) => {
    member_user = user;
    return fabric_client.setUserContext(member_user);
}).then(() => {
    console.log('User1 was successfully registered and enrolled and is ready to interact with the fabric network');
}).catch((err) => {
    console.error('failed to register:' + err);
    if (err.toString().indexOf('Authorization') > -1) {
        console.error('Authorization failures may be caused by having admin credentials from a previous CA instance.\n' +
            'Try again after deleting the contents of the store dircetory' + store_path);
    }
});
```

but I get some mistake in the terminal

```
Successfully loaded admin from persistence
Failed to register: Error: fabric-ca request register failed with errors [[ { code: 20, message: 'Authorization failure' } ]]
Authorization failures may be caused by having admin credentials from a previous CA instance.
Try again after deleting the contents of the store directory /home/swenw/hyfa/fabric-samples/fish/fishnetwork/webapp/hfc-key-store
```

I check the docker logs ca.example.com, I get some information:

```
2021/03/13 06:48:59 [DEBUG] Received request for /api/v1/register
2021/03/13 06:49:00 [DEBUG] Received registration request from : { Name:user1 Type:client Secret:**** MaxEnrollments:1 Affiliation:org1.department1 Attributes:[] CAName:ca.example.com  }
2021/03/13 06:49:00 [INFO] 172.23.0.1:60634 POST /api/v1/register 401 25 "Invalid token in authorization header: Token signature validation failed"
```

I don't know how to correct it, please help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why I success now. I just

```
rm -rf hfc-key-store
```

But I swear I tried this way for many times, why this time get success? exhausted but thanksful.